# How to open a new window in python from another window?

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter, window

I have a problem with tkinter. I need to open a new windows, with some parametrics data when the user press a button. The issues is that the methos "set" of the Entry don't work when I create the new window, but it works when I create the window from the main class. What can I do to resolve this problem?
this is the button:

```
Button(self.frameTabella, text="prenota", command=lambda id=ConcreteLibro.getIdentificativo():self.prenotaLibro(id)).grid(row=i, column=14)
```

this is the code of the new window:

```
class GUIPrestitoLibro:
    import datetime

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.GestioneLibri=GestioneLibri()
        self.finestraPrestito=Tk()
        self.finestraPrestito.geometry()
        self.finestraPrestito.title("Prestito/consultazione")
        today = datetime.today()

        idLibroLabel=Label(self.finestraPrestito, text="ID libro:").grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.idLibro=StringVar(value=id)
        idLibro=Entry(self.finestraPrestito, textvariable=self.idLibro, state="readonly").grid(row=1, column=1)

        idUtenteLabel=Label(self.finestraPrestito, text="ID utente:").grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.idUtente=StringVar()
        idUtente=Entry(self.finestraPrestito, textvariable=self.idUtente).grid(row=2, column=1)

        dataInizioPrestitoLabel=Label(self.finestraPrestito, text="Data inizio prestito:").grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.dataInizioPrestito=StringVar(value=today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
        dataInizioPrestito=Entry(self.finestraPrestito, textvariable=self.dataInizioPrestito, state="readonly").grid(row=3, column=1)

        dataFinePrestitoLabel=Label(self.finestraPrestito, text="Data fine prestito:").grid(row=4, column=0)
        self.dataFinePrestito=StringVar()
        dataFinePrestito=Entry(self.finestraPrestito, textvariable=self.dataFinePrestito).grid(row=4, column=1)

        registra=Button(self.finestraPrestito, text="conferma", command=self.registraPrestito).grid(row=5, column=0)
        resetta=Button(self.finestraPrestito, text="resetta", command=self.resettaCampi).grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.finestraPrestito.mainloop()


    def resettaCampi(self):
        self.idUtente.set("")
        self.dataFinePrestito.set("")

    def registraPrestito(self):
        self.GestioneLibri.prestitoLibro(self.idLibro.get(), self.idUtente.get(), self.dataInizioPrestito.get(), self.dataFinePrestito.get())
        self.finestraPrestito.destroy()
```

how can I make the class "GUIPrestitoLibro" instance of Toplevel?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this class creates a second instance of `Tk`. A tkinter app should always only have a single instance of `Tk`, and should call `mainloop()` exactly once.

If you need to create multiple windows, all windows but the root window must be instances of `Toplevel`, and you should not call `mainloop()` on any window but the root window.